# Is there a program like panel daemon or fire daemon for Ubuntu server 12.04?

Tags: server, webserver

I need a web style interface where I can log onto a website and restart certain processes.  I know that there is fire daemon and panel daemon that you use for windows.  I was wondering if anybody knew of a program like that for Ubuntu?

Comment: Please give some more information. Which type of processes are you talking about?

Comment: I run a program for gaming called big brother bot or (b3) for short.  I will be hosting multiple instances for other gaming communities and if they change something in there files or just need to restart, this program will allow them to log into a website and restart the process/program.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios is process monitoring application that also does automatic restarting.

http://www.nagios.org/

Smaller and easier to configure would be Monit

http://mmonit.com/monit/

Both of them does monitoring and automatic actions (like restarting or multiple process restarting).

Comment: Hey guys thank you for the information.  I will try them out and see how they go.